# Type predicate not being parsed by TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, eslint

I have a map function:

`const toolsImages = skillsData.tools.map(tool => urlFor(tool.asset).url())`

The type of `toolsImages` is `(string | null)[]`. I want to narrow the type to just `string[]`. I have used a type predicate return type function that basically narrows the type to what I want.

Here:

```
function notEmpty<T>(value: T | null): value is T {
  return value !== null;
}
```

And then:

`const toolsImages = skillsData.tools.map(tool => urlFor(tool.asset).url()).filter(notEmpty)`

This works fine. The type has been narrowed down to what I want. The problem I am facing is that I get a parsing error whose details are:

```
  Line 14:46:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

  12 |
  13 | // customised filter function
> 14 | function notEmpty<T>(value: T | null): value is T {  
     |                                              ^       
  15 |   return value !== null;
  16 | }
  17 |
```

I have removed `eslint` from `devDependencies` and `eslintrc.json` so I doubt that is the problem. I am sceptical about `babel` but not sure.

Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks!

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./@types"
    ],
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,

    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.58",
    "@sanity/client": "^2.8.0",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^0.140.22",
    "@sanity/types": "^2.10.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.9",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.6.4",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "randomcolor": "^0.6.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-social-icons": "^5.2.0",
    "react-tag-cloud": "^1.3.2",
    "react-uuid": "^1.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and I'm completely baffled. My IDE parses the code fine, but then running `tsc` I get the same error.